# Bash-change directories in for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop

When you do a for loop, how do you change directories in the output?

Example:

```
for f in ./test/Sample1_out/*coords
do
    ./test/sort.pl --in1 "$f" --in2  "./test/Sample1_out/count.txt" --out "${f/.coords/.sorted}"
done
```

1. If I wanted to move up a directory to save the file in the "./test/" directory,  how would I do it?
2. If I wanted to have the loop iterate through all Sample folders, how could I do it?  (I tried `for f in ./test/*out/*coords; do ./test/sort.pl --in1 "$f" --in2 "./test/*out/count.txt" --out "${f/.coords/.sorted}` but my --in2 was emptied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle multiple directories, I would just add another loop:

```
for dir in ./test/*_out/; do
    for file in "$dir"/*.coords; do
        ./test/sort.pl --in1 "$file" --in2 "$dir/count.txt" \
                       --out "${file/.coords/.sorted}"
    done
done
```

Or you could use the glob on both levels at the same time, and use `dirname` or `${file%/*}` to get the name of directory the current file is in:

```
for file in ./test/*_out/*.coords; do
    ./test/sort.pl --in1 "$file" --in2 "${file%/*}/count.txt" \
                   --out "${file/.coords/.sorted}"
done
```

(`--in2 "./test/*out/count.txt"` won't work, the wildcard isn't expanded in quotes, you get a path with a literal asterisk.)

As for the output file, I'm not exactly sure what it is you want, but if you want all the output files in some other directory, then something like this:

```
outfile=${file##*/}       # remove directory part of path (or use basename)
                          # stick new path in, and change extension
outfile=/path/to/output/${outfile/.coords/.sorted}  
./test/sort.pl --in1 "$file" --in2  "$dir/count.txt" \
               --out "$outfile"
```

or if you want the "go up one directory", you could use `"${file%/*/*}/${file##*/}"` to transform `/foo/bar/abc.txt` to `/foo/abc.txt`.

Comment: Thanks.  Adding a directory loop worked, and helped immensely!